# Find the probability for all $a$.

Tags: probability-theory

The segment $L=[0,1]$ is randomly split into two segments. $m$ is the length of the smallest one. I need to find $P(m\leqslant a)\ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$.
I tried to take a random point $x$ on the $L$ and then wrote the definition of $m$: $m=min(x, 1-x)$. In these terms I had to find $P(min(x, 1-x)\leqslant a)$.

The first option: $min(x, 1-x)=x$.
$$
P_1(0\leqslant x\leqslant a)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{a-0}{1}=\frac{a}{2}
$$

The second option: $min(x, 1-x)=1-x$.
$$
P_2(0\leqslant 1-x\leqslant a)=P_2(1-a\leqslant x \leqslant 1)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1-(1-a)}{1}=\frac{a}{2}
$$

So, the desired probability is $P=P_1+P_2=a$

However, something tells me that I am wrong. May someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1/2]$. To see this, consider the case where the point chosen is within $[0,1/2)$ - then $m$ is the length of the segment to the left. If the point chosen is within $(1/2,1]$, then $m$ is the length of the segment to the right. Each of these cases are equally likely, and within each case $m$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1/2]$. So for $0\leqslant a\leqslant 1/2$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(m\leqslant a) = 2a.
$$